# How to save notebook widget state in Github?

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I can't manage to show widgets on notebooks I upload on github.
I am sure I have saved the widget state, in fact if I download the notebook again and I open it in VSC or JNotebook it shows the outputs correctly without requiring it to be run.
All the outputs are plotly figures.
Am I missing any step?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently all plotly figure can't be rendered in github because they're interactive.
In order to show them you need to use

```
fig.show('svg')
```

Or

```
fig.show('png')
```

To render the notebook correctly.